# How to set gradient as text color as well as add stroke around it in TextView Android?

Tags: java, android, textview, gradient

I want to set gradient as textcolor and also at the same time I want text to have a solid stroke around it as well in a `TextView`. So far what I have achieved is text can only show gradient or the stroke, not both at the same time.

I've created a custom class with extended `TextView` and I am using the following methods:

**Using this to draw stroke:**

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(_strokeWidth);
setTextColor(_strokeColor);
```

**Which gives me this result:**

[image]

**Using following code to add gradient:**

```
Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0f, 0f, getWidth(), getTextSize(), gradientColorsArray, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                paint.setShader(textShader);
```

**And It gives me the following result:**

[image]

The problem is when I combine the above two methods, The stroke is drawn but the color of the stroke is the same as the gradient I am giving to paint object.

**Following is the result I want to achieve. It would be great if somebody can guide me on how to achieve desired results.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after waiting for more than 4 days and lots of research, I am finally able to succeed to achieve the desired output.

The mistake I was making is while drawing a stroke on a paint object, I am setting the stroke color as `textcolor`. What I did this time was I created a `LinearGradient()` object and gave it to `paint.shader` while setting the `paintStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke)`.

```
Paint paint = this.getPaint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0f, 0f, getTextSize(), getTextSize(), mOutlineColor, mOutlineColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
```

And after setting the stroke in `onDraw()` method of my `CustomTextView` class, I called the `super.onDraw(canvas)`

Then I create a new `LinearGradient()` object for the gradient colors as follow:

```
 Paint paint = this.getPaint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        Shader linearShader = new LinearGradient(0f, 0f, getWidth(), getTextSize(), colors, null,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(linearShader);
```

Finally calling the `super.onDraw(canvas)` again and this gives my `textview` a stroke as well as gradient as textColor.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for it from day one when I started my project, and now can remove my text image to use right one!